# Eslint/Prettier integration with Intelij running really slowly

Tags: intellij-idea, eslint, prettier

I'm trying to integrate Eslint/Prettier in Intellij but I have one important constraint:

I want the Prettier formatting to be ran via Eslint. The reason for this is that I have important Eslint rules that I need to run with autofix on each save (along with Prettier) (Rule example - `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`). I cannot have this rule run autofix in a pre-commit hook, since it's fix can change the way the code behaves.

I managed to get everything working by defining all Prettier plugins/config inside Eslint and creating a File Watcher that runs Eslint on the Current file on each save.

**My problem is** - in VSCode it runs nicely, but in Intellij each save takes multiple seconds to run ESlint fix.

Does anyone use a similar setup and have it working nicely in Intellij?

Comment: Some time can be spent on 'Save all' performing. The file watcher is only triggered when all operations related to saving are completed. How much time does it take for the progress indicator to appear after invoking 'Save' action?

Is it faster if you run ESLint on the same file in the command line?